# changing the text of the button when clicking them

Tags: javascript, html, button, text, onclick

The follwowing is a button in my html code!

```
<input type='button'onclick='change()' id='processorder'  class='btn btn-success' value='Process order'>"
```

The following is the javascript function used by me to change the text of the button when it is clicked!(from Process order to Complete)!

```
var elem = document.getElementById("processorder");
if (elem.value=="Process order") elem.value = "Process order";
else elem.value = "Complete";
```

Though the above function seems to be correct its not working! how can i correct this issue?

Comment: Your if/else is reversed...If "process order", then make it "processor order" is how it reads right now, making it seem like it never changes

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying this:

`var elem = document.getElementById("processorder");
    if (elem.value=="Process order") elem.value = "Complete";
    else elem.value = "Process order";`

If the value is Process Order,then you have to change the value to complete else it should be process order.

I made a quick sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/fj4v4wqp/

Comment: Thanx alot! if i want to change the text of this button "Complete" using javascript how can achieve it?  <button onclick='change()' id='processorder'  class='btn btn-success' >Process order </button>